# Is there python support for Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-synapse

**What I am trying to do?**

Glue-Athena-like process.

1. Data in S3
2. AWS Glue (create metadata tables)
3. Tables can be queried using Athena via boto3 (python library)

**Problem I am facing in Azure Cloud**

~Trying to replicate the above process using Azure Synapse Analytics~

1. Data in linked Azure Storage container
2. Azure Data Factory (create external tables)
3. How to make T-SQL queries on the external tables using python?

Is there any python library to make T-SQL calls to the external tables created in Azure Synapse workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. PyODBC works with Synapse. It's not perfect but I use it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python

Note that installing it can be a bit tricky. You need the Python package, but also the ODBC driver and the apt package unixodbc-dev.

Here is the part of my dockerfile that does it on Ubuntu 18.04

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y libpq-dev unixodbc-dev apt-transport-https ca-certificates

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
&& curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
&& apt update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt install -y msodbcsql17
```

Comment: You're right, the above helps with the initial setup. Enquired about this on the [MSFT forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/425844/does-azure-synapse-analytics-have-support-for-pyth.html). Able to make it work quite smoothly. To note: need to ensure we create scoped credentials prior to creating datasources/external tables in Azure Synapse, if not there'll be access issues.